# A question regarding the constant of integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the indefinite integral $\int\sin(2x) dx$. There appear to be three seemingly different answers once this integral is evaluated. These are $\frac{-1}{2} \cos(2x) + C$, $\sin^2(x) + C$ and $-\cos^2(x) + C$. This is because all three functions differ only by a constant and thus differentiating them yields $\sin(2x)$. Is it therefore simply a matter of convention which one we decide to choose?

In a somewhat more artificial sense, one could say $\int\ 2x dx = (x+n)(x-n) + C$ for any $n \in  \mathbb{R}$. Why this is invalid makes more sense because we expand it and add $-n^2$ to $C$ which will give the accepted answer of $x^2 + C$ (the new $C$ is different, of course). Is this simply done for convenience? Can this rule be generalized/formalized in some way such that more tricky functions, in which the extra constant isn't quite as conspicuous as it is with basic polynomials, can be tackled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The principle behind the "$+C$" notation is that the value of an
antiderivative is really a *class* of functions.
Any two members of that class of functions differ by a constant.

Hence if $F(x)$ is a member of that class, then you can write any
other member of the class in the form $F(x) + C,$ where $C$ is
the appropriate constant.
In principle, any member of the class is on equal standing with any
other member, so I would say there is (in principle) no reason why you
*must* write $\int 2x\;dx = x^2 + C$ rather than (for example)
$\int 2x\;dx = (x^2 - 4) + C$.
In the case of an explicit constant term (such as $-4$), however,
it seems unnecessary to carry such a term through calculations
when there is already an arbitrary constant term $C$ in the formula.
So it seems unlikely that one would want to do so.

In the example of the multiple representations of $\int\sin(2x) \;dx$
which you gave, the same principle applies, but in this case,
where $\sin^2 x = -\cos^2 x + 1$, one would hardly want to
write $\int\sin(2x) \;dx = (-\cos^2 x + 1) + C$
just to make the answer "the same" as $\int\sin(2x) \;dx = \sin^2 x + C$;
one would more likely write $\int\sin(2x) \;dx = -\cos^2 x + C$,
since $-\cos^2 x$ is just as much a member of the
desired class of functions as $\sin^2 x$ is.

So congratulations on presenting a good example of what the
$\int f(x)\;dx = F(x) + C$ notation really means.

Comment: Nice explanation! +1

Answer (score 2):

I think you are right in your second paragraph; the choice is simply for convenience. Based on your choice of form for the antiderivative you will get a different $C$, but once you specify a *particular* antiderivative (say by specifying that it pass through the point $(1,2)$ for instance), the actual result will be uniquely determined no matter which choice of equivalent algebraic form you have picked.

Also, by your reasoning in the second paragraph I would say that $\int 2x \,dx = (x+n)(x-n) + C$ is equally as valid as writing $x^2+C'$, provided one distinguishes $C$ and $C'$. As you say, they end up being the same thing, and as I mentioned above, the difference between how you write your antiderivative is virtually nil once you have selected an antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct, but a bit misleading, because your answer, $(x + n)(x - n) + C$ has two constants in it, but the two constants are not independent of one another. It looks like you have a sequence of functions parameterized by two variables ($n$ and $C$), but really it is only parametrized by one.

For instance, say we define $f(x) = \int 2xdx$ and specify $f(0) = 1$. Then $(x - n^2 + C)|_{x=0} = 1$, so $-n^2 + C = 1$. Thus we can see here that the value of $C$ depends on the value of $n$ by $C = 1 + n^2$ (or visa versa).

If you want to define an anti-derivative in a such a way that the constant is fixed, there are two standard ways. One is to specify a value at a point (like $f(0) = 1$ as above). No single point will create a "nice" result for every function (for example, for $f(x) = \int \sin(x) dx = -\cos(x) + C$ if $f(0) = 1$ then $C = 0$ and $f(x) = -\cos(x)$, but for $f(x) = \int \cos(x) dx = \sin(x) + C$ if $f(0) = 1$ then $C = 1$ and $f(x) = \sin(x) + 1$).

The other is to define use a definite integral, where one of the limits is a variable, like $$\int_0^x \sin(t) dt$$ (it's good practice to use a different variable inside the integral to avoid being confused).

These two ways are really just the same thing. For example, the above integral is $-\cos(x) - -cos(0) = -\cos(x) + 1$. But if we compute $f(x) = \int\sin(x)dx = -\cos(x) + C$ with $f(0) = 0$ then $0 = -\cos(0) + C = -1 + C$, so $C = 1$, giving the same answer, $-\cos(x) + 1$ (and that always holds because if $f(x) = \int_0^xF(t) dt$ then $f(0) = \int_0^0F(t)dt = 0$).